# Display the list of all songs of a singer who sang the song 'Lungi Dance' Without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to find out list of songs who sang by singer who sang 'lungi dance' song. it is possible to find it without subquery. In below code i am able to display songs names that belongs to singer but how can i find singer name by it's song title without the use of subquery.

```
SELECT SongTitle
FROM Singer
INNER JOIN Songs ON Songs.Singer_id=Singer.Singer_id
WHERE Singer_Name='Bohemia'
```

Comment: The query above doesn't use a sub-query, it uses a join.  You need to somehow compare values in both tables.  Not sure what you're after here...

Comment: It would be nice if you showed us sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without subquery (, but a second JOIN):

```
SELECT songsOut.SongsTitle
FROM Songs songsCompare
JOIN Singer singer ON (singer.id = songsCompare.Singer_id)
JOIN Songs songsOut ON (songsOut.Singer_id = singer.Singer_id)
WHERE lower(songsCompare.SongTitle) = 'lungi dance';
```

Comment: it's working but i want show just SongsTitle Column. It's possible.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Can you help me where can i learn these JOIN and problem solving skills

Comment: @xerx593 :) OK OK, I give in. I separated the question as reading while answering the last part as its own question. You win :) Bonus even for using `LOWER()`.

Comment: still, good & clean sql @Brien, ty! It's a race sometimes but no fight, i hope xDxD

Comment: @RajanJosan: JOIN - think always of a "(conditional) cartesian product" ... understand the difference between right-left-inner(normal) ...and #problem solving: Keep cool, and always remember the solution is "encoded" in each problem...just learn to "unfold" :)

Comment: Ok Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Question in title:

> Display the list of all songs of a singer who sang the song 'Lungi
>   Dance'

```
SELECT s3.SongTitle
FROM Singer s1
INNER JOIN Songs s2 ON s1.Singer_id = s2.Singer_id
INNER JOIN Songs s3 ON s2.Singer_id = s3.Singer_id
WHERE s2.SongTitle = 'lungi dance'
```

[image]

[[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/ASNEX40194)

---

Question near end of original post:

> How can i find singer name by it's song title without the use of
>   subquery

You can do this just by changing the search condition in your `WHERE`:

```
SELECT s1.Singer_name, s2.SongTitle
FROM Singer s1
INNER JOIN Songs s2 ON s1.Singer_id = s2.Singer_id
WHERE s2.SongTitle = 'lungi dance'
```

[image]

---

Example:

```
;WITH Singer (Singer_id, Singer_name) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'Bohemia' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Joe' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Sam')
, Songs (SongTitle, Singer_id) AS (
    SELECT 'lungi dance', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joes Song', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sams Song', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'lungi love', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joes Hit', 2)

SELECT s1.Singer_name, s2.SongTitle
FROM Singer s1
INNER JOIN Songs s2 ON s1.Singer_id = s2.Singer_id
WHERE s2.SongTitle = 'lungi dance'
```

---

Now you can search for multiple songs, and return the Singer:

```
SELECT s1.Singer_name, s2.SongTitle
FROM Singer s1
INNER JOIN Songs s2 ON s1.Singer_id = s2.Singer_id
WHERE s2.SongTitle IN ('Joes Song', 'Joes Hit', 'lungi dance')
```

[image]